# Edit gopro 4k videos in virtualdub

Tags: virtualdub

I am trying to edit video filmed by Hero4 Black in VirtualDub. So far I opened video in GoPro Studio and converted it to mpeg file. However when trying to open it in VirtualDub with Mpeg4 plugin I am getting error about audiocodec 00ff. I installed ac3acm codec and x264vfw but still have the same error. Anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

VirtualDub was made to operate exclusively on AVI files; however, a plugin API was added from version 1.7.2 which allows the import of other formats. Appropriate video and audio codecs need to be installed.